# I was trying to add TextSpan as the children of TextSpan, but I'm getting error

Tags: flutter, dart

The error which I'm getting is :

" The argument type 'TextSpan' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List? "

Here is the code:

```
Widget buildSignUpBtn() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print('SignUp Pressed'),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: TextSpan(
            text: 'Don\'t have an Account',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Don\'t have an Account',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please help me to fix this!

Comment: Cannot have ,children , which will require Array of children properties inside TextSpan , refer to this doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html mentioned by @munsifali ,  and note that , children , is outside and contains TextSpans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is taking list of TextSpan in the children property just like this:

```
RichText(
 text: TextSpan(
text: 'Hello ',
style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
children: const <TextSpan>[
  TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
],
),
)
```

you can read more about RichText in the official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)